# Как верно расставить знаки препинания в предложении с косвенным вопросом

Tags: пунктуация

Главным вопросом для отбора в каталог “Культурные коды Иркутска” был: (-, ,)  является ли данный предмет, событие, человек и проч. отражением культурного кода только города Иркутска (его событий, людей, среды, привычек, слов и т.д.).